# Error unicode export csv file - Laravel/Excel

Tags: php, csv, laravel-5, export, maatwebsite-excel

I have a problem, can you guys help me ?

I use Maatwebsite/Laravel-excel to export japanese text from database to csv file.

**When I open export file using MS Excel, I got a lot of symbols.**

[image]

**But when I open it using Notepad++ or upload to Google Drive, I got exactly I want.**

[image]

How can I fix it ?

This is my code :

```
    public function export($type, $properties, $data)
{
    if (in_array($type, self::EXPORT_TYPE)) {
        try {
            $export = Excel::create($properties['_title'], function ($excel) use ($data, $properties) {
                $excel->sheet('Sheet', function ($sheet) use ($data) {
                    foreach ($data as $item) {
                        $sheet->fromArray($item);
                    }
                });
            })->export('csv');
        } catch (Exception $error) {
            throw $error;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved it.
if any one get this problem, try edit config/excel.php : change `'use_bom' => false` to `'use_bom' => true`.

Hope this helpful !

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Btw can you explain what exactly is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't edit the config file of Maatwebsite library. Because in production environment, Maatwebsite will be update whenever you run command `compose install/update`. So your config is also false.